# Need to upload multiple attachements VisualForce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment, html

I have a requirement to upload multiple attachment in Visual Force page.

When i click on the attachment button i should be asked for how many attachment and then system show show the correct number of "Browse" options to do the attachment".

I specifically want to do it with the help of HTML as this is not refreshing my entire page when i add an attachment.

I have achieved my requirement, but the problem is after selecting the drop down value as "3" and then if i reduce the value to "2" the number of "Browser" options is not getting reduced.

any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<apex:page >
     <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
         <apex:inputText />
            </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
            <apex:pageblock >
              <apex:pageBlockSection >
              <select onchange="showattach();" id="sizeofatta">        <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<div id="1a" style="display:none;">
<input type="file" name="img" />
</div>
<div id="2a" style="display:none;">
<input type="file" name="img" />
</div>
<div id="3a" style="display:none;">
<input type="file" name="img" />
</div>    
 <input type="submit"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection></apex:pageblock>
   <script>
function showattach(){
    alert('method called');
    var atcount=document.getElementById("sizeofatta").value;
    alert(atcount);
         for(var i=1;i<=atcount;i++){
          alert(i);
         var atdivid=i+'a';
         alert(atdivid);
         document.getElementById(atdivid).style.display = "block";
          } 
           for(var i=atcount++;i<3;i++){
        alert('fdgfgf'+i);
        var atdivid=i1+'a';
        alert(atdivid);
        document.getElementById(atdivid).style.display = "none";
    }           
}
      </script> 
      <style>
         #1a,#2a,#3a,#4a{
             dispaly:none;
                  }
        </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated working code. I have just reversed the two loops. Everytime you should first hide all file input fields and then show accordingly. Also I have made the first input field always visible as your dropdown starts from 1. Hope this helps.

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:inputText />
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
  <apex:pageblock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
      <select onchange="showattach();" id="sizeofatta">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
      <div id="1a" style="display:block;">
        <input type="file" name="img" />
      </div>
      <div id="2a" style="display:none;">
        <input type="file" name="img" />
      </div>
      <div id="3a" style="display:none;">
        <input type="file" name="img" />
      </div>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageblock>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function showattach() {
            for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                var atdivid = i + 'a';
                document.getElementById(atdivid).style.display = "none";
            }           
            var atcount = document.getElementById("sizeofatta").value;
            for (var i = 1; i <= atcount; i++) {
                var atdivid = i + 'a';
                document.getElementById(atdivid).style.display = "block";
            }
        }  
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
        #1a,#2a,#3a,#4a{
            dispaly:none;
        }  
  </style>
</apex:page>
```